# How to add a scroll bar in the day of the calendar that the content inside is more than the fixed height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a calendar with fixed width and height, and if the content in that day is too much, it will have a scroll bar in side the day (Only appear if there have many contents).

I am trying to limit the height of the calendar even if there are content inside each day. However, if the content inside the day is more than the height, it will:

[image]

Code:

```
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

When I try to add a scroll bar with `display: block;` and `overflow-y: scroll;` it become:

[image]

Code:

```
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But it does give me what I want for that particular day:

[image]

SO, how can I add a scroll bar for the day that have longer content than the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `td` to `display: block` will change the way the `td` works.

I suggest that you add the content of the table cell inside of another `div` and manipulate the `width`, `height` and `overflow` on the div instead of the `td`

This way the table elements will act as table elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/tpsznme3/15/

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y#values) for the values of the `overflow-y` CSS property:

> `scroll`: Content is clipped if necessary to fit vertically in the padding box. Browsers display scrollbars whether or not any content is actually clipped. (This prevents scrollbars from appearing or disappearing when the content changes.) Printers may still print overflowing content.

> `auto`: Depends on the user agent. If content fits inside the padding box, it looks the same as visible, but still establishes a new block-formatting context. Desktop browsers provide scrollbars if content overflows.

Therefore you should be using `auto` if you want the scrollbars only to be displayed when content is actually clipped.

Comment: I have uses `auto` and it works. However, the calendar will looks like the second image. It will become only one column left.